# Delete statement using PDO, PHP and MYSQL using primaryKey & checkBox

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to delete multiple entry in database. I'm using a checkbox to determine what data I need to delete. Once I tick the checkbox, its sending me the value of my primary key which I use to delete it. So far I have come up with this

when I try to delete single or multiple data, it goes straight to success page which successfully count the number of intended amount of deleted player. But nothing happens when I show all tables.

HTML/PHP code

```
            <?php
                $self = htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
                echo "<form id='delete' method='POST' action='$self'>";
            ?>
    <div class="content">                   
            <h3>Delete Athlete</h3>
            <hr>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Select Player</th><th>Photo</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Gender</th><th>Sport</th><th>Country</th><th>Population</th><th>Flag</th>
                </tr>
                    <?php
                        foreach($showResult as $row)
                        {
                            echo("<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='checkdelete[]' value='$row[athleteID]'>$row[athleteID]</td>
                            <td><img class='photo' src='files/$row[image]' alt='$row[lastName].jpg'/></td>
                            <td>$row[firstName]</td><td>$row[lastName]</td>
                            <td><img class='genderImg' src='files/$row[gender].png' alt='$row[gender].jpg'/></td>
                            <td>$row[sport]</td><td>$row[countryName]</td><td>$row[population]</td>
                            <td><img class = 'flag' src='files/flags/$row[flag]' alt='$row[flag].jpg'/></tr>");
                        }
                    ?>                      
            </table>    
    <br><input type="submit" name="deleteAth" value="Delete">               
    </div>
</body>
```

and I have this code for PHP

```
<?php
```

include 'connect.inc.php';

```
try   // select statement for the output page/delete page
{
    $showJoinedTbl = "SELECT athleteID,image, firstName, lastName, gender, sport, 
    countryName, population, flag from athTbl join
    counTbl on athTbl.countryID = counTbl.countryID ORDER by firstName";
    $showResult = $pdo->query($showJoinedTbl);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    $error = 'Select statement error';
    include 'error.html.php';
    exit();
}
$dataCorrect = true;
if (isset($_POST['deleteAth']))
{           
    try
    {
        $valueID = $_POST['checkdelete'];
        $N = count ($valueID);
        for ($i=0; $i; $i++)
        {
            $deleteQry = $db->prepare("DELETE from athTbl WHERE athleteID= ?");
            echo ("$valueID[$i]");

            //$stmt = $pdo->prepare($deleteQry);
            $stmt->bindValue(1,$valueID[$i]);
            $stmt->execute();
        }   //when I try to delete single or multiple data, it goes straight to success page which successfully count the number of intended amount of deleted player. But nothing happens when I show all tables.
    }
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
        $error = 'Error deleting data from athleteTbl';
        include 'error.html.php';
        exit();
    }
    include 'DeleteSuccess.html.php';           // output screen if I deleted it successfully.
}
else
{
    include 'Delete.html.php';
}   
?>
```

Comment: form is in HTML/PHP. The $showResult which echo the table with checkBox per athleteID shown in Delete.html.php

Comment: First you do the select, and then you process the delete. Therefore the selected results will still have the records you want to delete because the delete statement has not run yet.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your loop:

```
...
$N = count ($valueID);
for ($i=0; $i; $i++)
           ^^ 0 on the first iteration
{
     ...
```

Your loop will run while the condition (the middle value) is `true`. You set `$i` to 0 which evaluates to `false` so your loop never runs.

Or, from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php):

> In the beginning of each iteration, expr2 is evaluated. If it
>   evaluates to TRUE, the loop continues and the nested statement(s) are
>   executed. If it evaluates to FALSE, the execution of the loop ends.

You probably want:

```
...
$N = count ($valueID);
for ($i=0; $i < $N; $i++)
{
     ...
```

Comment: thanks! have managed to have it working now. apart from what you pointed out, I used $db too instead of $pdo->prepare lol... I think time to sleep now! Thanks so much to you! Little mistake makes programming life miserable lol